# jQuery scroll - trigger plugin only once

Tags: jquery, triggers, scroll

I'm trying to trigger this plugin when it's visible on scroll only once.

```
// Fun Facts Counter

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var bh = $(window).height();
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        var el = $('.timer');
        var eh = el.height();
        if ( st >= (100 + eh) - bh ) {
            el.countTo({
                speed: 2000,
                refreshInterval: 20
            });
        }

    });
```

The problem is, I have also navbar stick to the top on scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('fixed');
            $('body').css('padding-top', '97px');
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed');
            $('body').css('padding-top', '0');
        }
    });
```

So when I tried to use .on and .off both elements stopped working.
How to make only first plugin fire once? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following will accomplish firing the first plugin function only once:

```
   var flag = 0;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
       if($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this).height() - 200){
           if (flag == 1){
              return false;
           }
           else{
              var bh = $(window).height();
              var st = $(window).scrollTop();
              var el = $('.timer');
              var eh = el.height();
              if ( st >= (100 + eh) - bh ) {
                  el.countTo({
                      speed: 2000,
                      refreshInterval: 20
                  });
              }
              flag = 1;
           }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't work. It runs the script on page load, not when the counter is visible. It's at the bottom of the site, so before I scroll down the script is already done. Here is the website URL http://coffeecreamthemes.com/themes/perfectcouple/site/demo1-full/

Comment: So you want to script to run only when the user had scrolled to the bottom of the page to where the counter is visible?

Comment: Please see edited. Note 200 in the if statement resembles the measurement in pixels from the bottom of the page, where the counter is visible.